# Cannot import Selenium packages in Eclipse after configuring build path

Tags: eclipse, selenium-rc

I've downloaded the selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar in order to configure selenium RC and also configured it in project in Eclipse like that:

[image: build path configuring]

Now when trying to download selenium package via eclipse code, Import option isn't displayed for 'Selenium' and not for DefaultSelenium.

[image: no import option]

what could be the reason?

Comment: You are using an outdated Eclipse version (as I can see by the toolbar icons) that might not be able to read the JAR file compiled with a newer Java version. Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades).

Comment: Hi, I've upgraded eclipse and problem still occurs . Do you think I need to upgrade Java as well?

Comment: In the _Package Explorer_ view, can you expand the `selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar` node to show where the `Selenium` type is contained in that JAR?